# Elegant way to for loop several statements in gnuplot 4.6?

Tags: loops, nested, gnuplot

I am trying to have a plot statement loop over several couplets of functions plots. The order of the statements is important because it creates overdraw in the right order.

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist

datfile="overdraw.dat"
num=3
skip=40

set table datfile
g(x,t)=exp(-x**2+{0,1}*2*t*x)
set samples 501
plot [-2:2][0:5] for [ii=0:num] real(g(x,ii))
unset table

xspeed=0.1
yspeed=0.3

## this works but creates overdraw in the wrong order
#plot [-2:2] \
#  for [ii=0:num] datfile index ii u ($1+xspeed*ii):($2-yspeed*ii) not w l lt ii lw 8 \
#, for [ii=0:num] datfile index ii every skip u ($1+xspeed*ii):($2-yspeed*ii) not w p lt ii pt 7 ps 4 \
#

set macro

## this works but is cumbersome
plotstring="NaN not"
do for [ii=0:num] {
  plotstring=plotstring.sprintf(", \"%s\" index %i u ($1+xspeed*%i):($2-yspeed*%i) not w l lt %i lw 8", datfile, ii, ii, ii, ii)
  plotstring=plotstring.sprintf(", \"%s\" index %i every skip u ($1+xspeed*%i):($2-yspeed*%i) not w p lt %i pt 7 ps 4", datfile, ii, ii, ii, ii)
}
plot [-2:2] @plotstring


## this doesn't work because the for loop only applies to the first statement
#plotboth='datfile index ii u ($1+xspeed*ii):($2-yspeed*ii) not w l lt ii lw 8\
#, datfile index ii every skip u ($1+xspeed*ii):($2-yspeed*ii) not w p lt ii pt 7 ps 4'
#plot [-2:2] for [ii=0:num] @plotboth


## this gives an error message
plot [-2:2] for [ii=0:num] { \
  datfile index ii u ($1+xspeed*ii):($2-yspeed*ii) not w l lt ii lw 8\
, datfile index ii every skip u ($1+xspeed*ii):($2-yspeed*ii) not w p lt ii pt 7 ps 4 \
}
```

As you can see, I made it work in the right order by appending to a string holding a plot statement. It would be nice, however, to be able to just put brackets around the plot statements as indicated at the end of my example.

Submitting several plot/replot statements seems not to be an option, as that creates pages in some in some terminals (e.g. postscript). I would regard multiplot as cumbersome, too. Perhaps there is an elegant syntax that I have overlooked?

Comment: Is this question still of relevance? Can you provide an example of your input? (I might spend more time trying to generate one than coming up with an answer).

Comment: @Schorsch, please uncomment the various commented blocks in my MWE above to follow what the problem is.
My MWE produces data up to the `unset data` statement that you can play with.
`## This works but is cumbersome`
is the block that produces output that I like, but I don't like the coding.
`## this gives an error message`
is how I would like to be doing things, as it is more systematic.
It may be that this will work only in future versions of gnuplot but I wanted to ask if there is a way of doing something similar (i.e. controlling the order of overdraw in a loop explicitly) already now.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having two commands, one for the lines and one for the points, I'd suggest one command for a line with points, but - because there are many data-points - skipping some in the plot (as you intend with the `skip` variable).
Based on your dataset, I used the following code to generate your plot:

```
plot [-2:2] for [ii=0:num] datfile index ii u ($1+xspeed*ii):($2-yspeed*ii) \
  not w lp lt ii lw 8 pt 7 pi skip ps 4
```

I used the `w lp` command (which is short for `with linespoints`) to have a line **and** points, and the `pi skip` (which is short for `pointinterval skip`) to skip `40` datapoints between the symbols. More information on `linespoints` and `pointinterval` can be found in the [documentation](http://www.gnuplotting.org/manpage-gnuplot-4-6/#x1-84000II).

Comment: thanks I was not aware of this option for linespoints! I was looking for a general way to control drawing order to include, for example, fence plots, so I am withholding "accepted" or now. But I am voting "useful".

Comment: @AnMarkm I almost expected that you wanted more than just a line with points. I appreciate the up-vote.